# How can you listen to keyup events from two tinymce editors on a single page?

Tags: jquery, events, tinymce, jquery-events

Right now, this is how I listen to a tinymce editor. It works perfect when there is only one editor.

```
tinymce.activeEditor.on('keyup', function(e) {
    $("#form-buttons-save").removeClass("disabled").addClass("submit-widget button-field context");
  });
```

However, this falls apart when there are two editors. It only listens to the bottom editor and not to both. How can I listen to both?

Comment: are you repeating ID's in the page?

Comment: I am not completely sure because I am using a cms and building a form. When I choose richText, it gives me a tinymce box. I don't have much control over the initialization of the tinymce.